# On Click edit text field second time shows default keyboard

Tags: android

sorry for bad English,
I have used Edit text field which shows custom keyboard. on click for first time it shows custom keyboard but if I click again that field it shows device default keyboard my code is

```
final EditTextNoKeyBoard eText = new EditTextNoKeyBoard(context);
                        eText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_border);
                        eText.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.appInputTextColor));
//                      eText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
//                       eText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        eText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                        eText.setInputType(0);
                        eText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
                        eText.setWidth(100);
                        eText.setSingleLine();
```

EditTextNoKeyBoard  class is

```
public class EditTextNoKeyBoard extends EditText
{

    public EditTextNoKeyBoard(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public EditTextNoKeyBoard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public EditTextNoKeyBoard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sanjay Chauhan I have tried this but all in vain

Answer (score 0):

On edit text focus hide the system keyboard

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: I have tested this solution but this is not working for me